# A question related to Probability(read body)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-probability

**Q. Out of 100 students two sections of 40 and 60 students are to be formed. If Jack and Jenny are among the 100 students, what is the probability that:
a) they end up in the same section?
b) they end up in different sections?**

I calculated the answer of the first part just fine, it came out to be:
(⁴⁰C₂+⁶⁰C₂)/¹⁰⁰C₂ =17/33

Now, to find the answer to the second part I could subtract the answer of the first part from 1 and get 16/33 which is the answer printed in my exercise book. However I’m in a bit of a dilemma.

If instead of thinking that way I say that there are two possibilities:

1. Jack ends up in A and Jenny in B.
   This would give the answer as:
   (⁴⁰C₁.⁶⁰C₁)/¹⁰⁰C₂
2. Jack ends up in B and Jenny in A.
   Which would again give the answer as:
   (⁴⁰C₁.⁶⁰C₁)/¹⁰⁰C₂

so the final answer would be 
2(⁴⁰C₁.⁶⁰C₁)/¹⁰⁰C₂ =32/33
and this answer does not match the answer in my book.

Can somebody tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: The probability that Jack is in $A$ and Jenny is in $B$ is half of what you say.  Your denominator should be $100\times 99$ as you need to pick a slot for Jack and then a slot for Jenny.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.